# quantization of Dirac field

Tags: quantum-field-theory

The general solution to the Dirac equation is a sum of plane wave solutions
$$
\psi(x) \sim \int d^3k \sum_r b_r(k) u_r(k)e^{-ikx} + d^\dagger_r(k) v_r(k)e^{+ikx}
$$
The basis spinors $u_r$ and $v_r$ are not eigenstates of chirality (though they are eigenstates of helicity). I can construct left- and right-handed chirality eigenstates of the $\gamma_5$ operator from linear sums of left- and right-handed helicity spinors.

From this, I can expand left- and right-handed chirality spinors $\psi_L$ and $\psi_R$ in plane wave solutions with creation and annihilation operators.

$\psi_L$ contrains operators that annihilate a left-handed helicity particle, and create a right-handed helicity anti-particle.

1. Why doesn't $\psi_L$ create/destroy only left-handed (anti)-particles? (or does the RH anti-particle have LH helicity, i.e. anti-particle here is CP)
2. Why doesn't $\psi_L$ create/destroy particles with definite chirality (only definite helicity)?

Comment: So I guess the answer is that $\psi$ creates and destroys particles and the (CP) anti-particles. The mass mixes the chirality, so we only create definite chiralities in the massless limit. The right-handed anti-particle spinor is the CP conjugate of the left-handed particle, and has $P_R \psi^c_R = 0$, i.e. it $C$ messes with chirality, so so $\psi_R^C$ belongs in the LH $\psi_L$ field.